# Qt Stylesheets : Unable to use ID Selector

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qstylesheet

I am learning to use the Qt Stylesheet to add different styles to my application. I looked online and saw the Qt Documentation which said that you can use something called `ID Selector` that can apply the theme to certain objects. This is how I implemented this feature :

```
QPushButton#button
{
    color:red;
}
```

But it doesn't work. It only works when I try without the `ID Selector`:

```
QPushButton
{
    color:red;
}
```

Why doesn't this work ? I used copy and paste, so I'm 100% sure that I didn't got the name wrong.

Comment: Did you [`yourButton->setObjectName(yourID);`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) the target QPushButton ?

Answer (score 5):

I found out the answer, and it's actually really simple. I forgot to add `button->setObjectName("Name");`, which caused the stylesheet to not know about the button. Just add in this line of code and it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

which version?
please tell me and sent the whole code.
because 4.7 4.8 5.2 5.3 5.5 5.8 have many different detail.

my be use can try

```
QStyleOption opt;  
opt.initFrom(this);  
QPainter p(this);  
style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
```